# Не показывать, если результата нет

Tags: php

Есть php скрипт, при запросы показывает информацию, если есть что показать.
Если есть результат показывает так:

```
**related key**
key 1
key 2
key 3
```

Если нет, то так:

```
**related key**
```

Как убрать related key,если нет результатов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то

```
if (trim($keywordi)){
echo "<h2>related key</h2> \n"; 
echo "$keywordi \n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, именно так!

Answer (score 0):

Убираешь в скрипте строку, которая отвечает за вывод `**related key**`

Comment: Так в том-то и дело, что если убрать, то даже когда есть результат, то не будет показывать **related key**

Comment: @jikol приведите код. Судя по всему ваша проблема элементарна, но стоило бы при ее решении отталкиваться от вашего варианта

Comment: В коде ни чего такого нет, просто я сам прописал так
echo "<h2>related key</h2>
\n";
echo "$keywordi
\n";
$keywordi - вывод инфы, если есть результат....
 Мне просто нужно как-то дописать что ли $keywordi

Comment: @jikol к сожалению вы  очень коряво объясняете. Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно выводить на страницу вышеуказанную информацию, если она есть и вообще ничего не выводить, если ее нет?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сначала посмотреть откуда берется данная строчка и оттуда убрать echo. Если же все равно показывается, значит Вы не там смотрите. Пройдитесь по файлам с поиском строки "related key" (галочки убрать) и посмотрите, где еще возможно данный вывод.